# Why my controller cannot get the model passed back from view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**my controller cannot get the model passed back from controller. I spend the whole morning could not figure it out, appropriated it if any one can help me out. Thank you!!!**

Added: I am kind of following this example, it only has form tags instead of ajax forms

[MVC4 Passing model from view to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339398/mvc4-passing-model-from-view-to-controller/16340663#16340663)

***Model***
it's a list of product entity, I am using .net entity framework for database access

```
public class VM_Products
{
    public List<FMST_Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
private FMSTEntities ctx = new FMSTEntities();

public ActionResult Index()
{
  VM_Products vmps = new VM_Products();

  vmps.Products = ctx.FMST_Product.ToList();

  return View("Index", vmps);
}

// when I step in, the SelectedProducts is always null ???
public ActionResult AddToCart(FMST_Product SelectedProducts)  
{
        return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@using FMST
@using FMST.Models
@model VM_Products

<ul id="products" class="list clear">           
            @foreach (var p in Model.Products)
            {
                <form action="POST" id=@p.ProductID>
                    <li class="clearfix">
                    @p.ProductID
                    <br>
                    @p.ProductName
                    <br>
                    @p.ProductDesc
                    <br>
                            @p.ProductPrice
                            <span class="darkview">
            @Html.ActionLink("Add To CT","AddToCart","Product",p);

                            </span>
                    </li>

            </form>   
            }
</ul>
```

Comment: One of the problems (I think there are more than 1) is that you are using the `@Html.ActionLink` and expecting it to work as `POST` but the `ActionLink` creates an `<a>` tag so only a `GET` if you want to `POST` something you need to use a form or AJAX.

Comment: if you put the page in a form tag and use a submit button the model will be passed back automatically  As the others have said if you want the model to go back without a post back you will need to do an ajax call and build the model in jquery

Comment: If you take a look at the example you are following, he is not actually posting anything, the `ActionLink` is just parameterizing the object (`product` in your case) and passing it to the controller's action as part of the `QueryString`.

Comment: I can get the product id by changing ActionLink to @Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCart", "Product", new { productid = p.ProductID }, ""), still no luck with passing the whole product object and get it in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your html helper from:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add To CT","AddToCart","Product",p);
```

to:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add To CT","AddToCart","Product",p,null);
```

Since you are specifying the `ControllerName` within your html helper you need to force the helper to use the correct overload by passing null as your last parameter.

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out a moment ago, I can either do @Html.ActionLink("Add To CT","AddToCart",p); This will go to the same controller or @Html.ActionLink("Add To CT","AddToCart","Product",p,null); which can be used to GET to another controller.  Thanks SOfanatic!!!

Comment: @user2418709 ok cool, since it helped don't forget to mark it as the answer.

Comment: I am sorry, where I can mark it as an answer? I don't see a button or link for that, it's my first time asking questions here. Thanks.

Comment: @user2418709 by the `0` with the up and down arrows, there a check mark you have to click that.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your AddToCart Action is expecting a list of Products, but you are passing in a single Product.

Can more than one Product be added to the cart in a single step?  Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I just changed the code, but still no luck.                               public ActionResult AddToCart(FMST_Product products)
        {
            return View();
        }