# How model is passed by browser to MVC controller action

Tags: post, model-view-controller, action

I want to understand how browser post request passes model to MVC controller action. I understand that form collection is passed in post request.

I do not understand how the whole view model is passed to MVC controller via HTTP in such a way that allows it to access model object(s).

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostDataExample(PostDataViewModel model)
{

    return Content(model.property1.ToString());

    **//How are we able to get above model from browser ?**
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific - what is the technology you're using?

Comment: this question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339398/mvc4-passing-model-from-view-to-controller

Comment: I am using ASP.Net MVC.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by the Model View Binder, which I only partly understand myself. [This](http://www.edandersen.com/2013/05/28/asp-net-mvc-basics-part-1-view-model-binding/) is a good starting point for reading.

Comment: My question is how server gets model object(.net object) while serving post request of browser as we know browser will send the data in string format. Which component doing serialization from string type to .net object