# Stop ASP.Net MVC from inserting URL parameters into Action Dictionary parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an `ASP.Net` `MVC` Application, in one of my `Controllers` I have an `Action` which receive parameters from the `POST`, this method has an optional parameter which is a `Dictionary`. But when I dont set anything in the `POST` for this parameter I am getting a `Dictionary` with the `Controller` and `Action` (which come from the `URL Route`)

My Method Definition:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Refresh(string startDate, string endDate, string systemCode, string tab, Dictionary<string, string[]> selectedHierarchyValues = null, bool refreshCache = false, List<MediaFilter> filters = null)
{
```

I know that I can get the data from the `POST` by using `Request.Form`
but I am trying to achieve this with some more elegant way.

Comment: You need to create a ViewModel so as to **utilize the MVC model binder**, when you post the form to your controller. This thread provides a simple, clear example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495717/passing-model-data-from-view-to-controller-and-using-its-values